# Bundler gives pg when I ask for sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

```
bundle show sqlite3
Could not find pg-0.14.1 in any of the sources
```

Any idea what's going on here? How can asking for sqlite3 get me Postgres? My Gemfile has sqlite3 set for development and pg for production, and I'm in the development environment.

I've since installed pg manually, which worked once I'd installed libpq-dev, and then after that, bundle show sqlite3 gives me sqlite3 as expected. But how could bundler have got this confused just because a different gem didn't install?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us your Gemfile.lock? I think some other gem may require pg.